# After updating from AppCenter: sudo apt autoremove convenient?

Tags: release-loki, updates, pantheon-terminal, appcenter, package

After updating through AppCenter I use to verify that everything is OK. When I run `sudo apt upgrade` sometimes the command tells me that some packages are not necessary and that I should use `sudo apt autoremove` (mostly related to kernel headers and the like).

Is this safe?
Should I leave those packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can only be sure if you review each package and it's dependency (time consuming)

I do autoremove every time and nothing bad happened yet, however people did complain in the past that it removed necessary packages

Comment: It mostly happens with old kernel sources when a new kernel has been installed. I know it's wise to leave another kernel just in case something happens with the new one. I have to make sure if auto remove preserve at least one spare kernel (last one) thus cleaning the system of old kernels source (rebooting in last kernel is enough for me if any problem arises: I don't see the point in having a big choice of kernels at start up when choosing boot with prior kernels). Is there any benefit leaving only a few kernels for a normal user?

Comment: I'm not an expert but In elementary so far I removed to older kernel (I think once). but not sure it's the right thing to do